# apache/php/htaccess - how to point two rewrites to a single file and keep query string?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

See, i have an online store where the language is handled through constants, so I have only one site with multiple languages. However, I want also custom URLs based in the language.

Let's say, "my_account.php" should be rewritten to "my-account" but also keep parameters, maybe one, or two, it depends upon the file.

I'll leave an example cause this will explain it better:

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^about$ about_us.php [L]
RewriteRule ^addresses$ addresses.php [L]
RewriteRule ^locations$ branches.php [L]
RewriteRule ^buying_policy$ buying.php [L]
RewriteRule ^cart$ cart.php [L]
RewriteRule ^cart/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ cart.php?step=$1&related=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact_us$ contact_us.php [L]
RewriteRule ^faq$ faq.php [L]
RewriteRule ^welcome$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^account$ my_account.php [L]
RewriteRule ^orders$ orders.php [L]
RewriteRule ^privacy_policy$ privacy.php [L]
RewriteRule ^product$ product_detail.php [L]
RewriteRule ^product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ product_detail.php?sku=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^promos$ promotions.php [L]
RewriteRule ^workshop$ repairments.php [L]
RewriteRule ^shop$ store.php [L]
RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ store.php?family=$1 [NC,L] 

RewriteRule ^acerca$ about_us.php [L]
RewriteRule ^direcciones$ addresses.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sucursales$ branches.php [L]
RewriteRule ^politicas_de_compra$ buying.php [L]
RewriteRule ^carrito$ cart.php [L]
RewriteRule ^carrito/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ cart.php?step=$1&related=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contactenos$ contact_us.php [L]
RewriteRule ^preguntas_frecuentes$ faq.php [L]
RewriteRule ^bienvenido$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^mi_cuenta$ my_account.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ordenes$ orders.php [L]
RewriteRule ^politicas_de_privacia$ privacy.php [L]
RewriteRule ^producto$ product_detail.php [L]
RewriteRule ^producto/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ product_detail.php?sku=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^promociones$ promotions.php [L]
RewriteRule ^reparaciones$ repairments.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tienda$ store.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tienda/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ store.php?family=$1 [NC,L] 

ErrorDocument 404 /web/404.php
```

This is not working though, it's like the spanish rewrites are messing up the english ones which were defined first and above spanish, in this case.